# How to change emoji size in com.vanniktech.emoji.EmojiTextView

Tags: android, emoji

I am trying to implement Emoji keyboard for a chat app. I am using https://github.com/vanniktech/Emoji library.

1. In emoji edittext emoji size is big enough but when i push send
   button it       shows small emoji in emoji textview.

   i couldn't see any attributes in the sample for emoji size.

   See the picture below for the problem. I want emojis in the textView
   as big as in editText.

   [image]
2. How to store text with resource id or code (replaces the emoji) to store it in the database and use later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use `app:emojiSize` attribute. This attribute will also work for `EmojiTextView`. (Here is [source](https://github.com/vanniktech/Emoji/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/vanniktech/emoji/EmojiTextView.java#L35).)
   Or use [EmojiTextView#setEmojiSize](https://github.com/vanniktech/Emoji/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/vanniktech/emoji/EmojiTextView.java#L52) method.
2. I am not sure. But the string that is taken by EmojiEditText#getText().toString() should contain unicode of emoji. So I think you can store this string to database and use it later. I Infer this from [source code](https://github.com/vanniktech/Emoji/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/vanniktech/emoji/EmojiHandler.java#L1018).

Answer (score 0):

Use `app:emojiSize="30sp"`

This can be used in `<com.vanniktech.emoji.EmojiTextView />` Or `<com.vanniktech.emoji.EmojiEditText />`